# HTML - CSS How to stop the header's movement while using the scroll bar

Tags: html, css

My headers table is moving while using the scroll bar. I tried different approaches without success.
I want to do this in css only.
Any ideas?

Here is my [code](http://jsfiddle.net/8c6317gL/).

Answer (score 1):

you have to `replace top: 0;` with `top: 2px;` cz there are two pixels between the top of the page and top of table++++edit+++

I think there is i better solution but i haven't found it yet.

The solution that I thought of is adding a `<div class="cover"></div>` with a white background and the same width and height of the header in the table. Then place this div under the header. Here is the CSS:

```
.cover::after {
  content: "";
  background: white;
  position: absolute;
  width: 367px;
  height: 48px;
  left: 3px;
}
```

But the bad thing about this is that you will have to place the "cover" manually each time you change the position of the table.